# Navigation-bar changes it's width after sticking to the top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The navigation bar is at a certain distance away from the top, after scrolling past the navigation-bar, it sticks to the top but unfortunately it's width expands beyond the container(it's defined in). The navigation-bar should retain it's original width, so how do I resolve it? Here's my github link too :- https://github.com/Archiie/MyPortfolio

```css
.affix {
 top: 0px;
 margin: 0px 20px;
}
.affix + .container {
 padding: 5px;
}

h1, h4 {
 text-shadow: 4px 5px 3px #A866B2; /*#DCD4F9, #F74554 moves to the right, moves down, thickness of text's shadow*/
}
.main-container {
 margin: 40px 0px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #4B004C ; /*#800000, #4B004C, #E6E6E6*/
}

#head_tag, #footer_tag {
 font-family: Tangerine, Monospace;
 color: white;
}
#head_tag {
 font-size: 100px;
 height: 300px;
}
#footer_tag {
 font-size: 50px;
}

.image {
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #000;
 height: 230px;
 width: 240px;
}
.img-responsive {
 margin: 20px auto;
}

.navbar {
 margin: 0px 20px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.info {
 font-family: Monospace;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: #E6E6E6; /*#4B004C, #E6E6E6*/
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 20px 20px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}
.boxSpacing {
 margin: 20px auto;
}
.pics {
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
}

#aboutMe, #portfolio, #contactMe {
 font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #6E326F;
}

.centeringIcon {
 display: block;
 text-align:center;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="10">
  <div class="container main-container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <h1 class="text-center" id="head_tag">Archita's Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <img src="images/Archi.jpg" class="img-responsive image">
    </div>
   </div>
     
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="365">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">  <!-- This navigation bar should not change it's width even after scrolling past it-->
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contactMe">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="info">
      <h3 class="text-center" id="aboutMe">About Me</h3>
      <p>I'm a new-bee in front-end technology. I used to work on ROR, R and Python but now I'm exploring HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, jQuery, JavaScript, AngularJS and ReactJS.</p>
      <p>I've also worked on several <span style="color:#960099">android projects </span>as well. I've also worked on highcharts and D3.</p>
     </div>

     <div class="info">
      <h3 class="text-center" id="portfolio">Portfolio</h3>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 boxSpacing">
        <img src="images/Project_1.png" class="img-responsive pics">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 boxSpacing">
        <img src="images/Project_1.png" class="img-responsive pics">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 boxSpacing">
        <img src="images/Project_1.png" class="img-responsive pics">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 boxSpacing">
        <img src="images/Project_1.png" class="img-responsive pics">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="info">
      <h3 class="text-center" id="contactMe">Contact</h3>
      <p><b>Here's my contact details:</b></p>
      <ul>
       <li>Name:- Archita Sundaray</li>
       <li>Phone no.:- +91 89514 88208</li>
       <li>email address:- archi.sundaray5@gmail.com</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <h4 class="text-center" id="footer_tag">~ made by Archita Sundaray</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 img-responsive">
     <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/archita-sundaray-b7240977/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin centeringIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 img-responsive">
     <a href="https://github.com/Archiie" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github centeringIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 img-responsive">
     <a href="https://twitter.com/Archi055" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter centeringIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 img-responsive">
     <a href="https://bitbucket.org/Archiie/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket centeringIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Now its working, when it is sticky then it's position fixed so you have to give it width or set left and right position

```css
.affix {
 top: 0px;
 margin: 0px 20px;
  width:1100px;
}
@media (max-width: 1199px)
{
.affix {
    width: 900px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 991px)
{
.affix {
    width: 680px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 768px)
{
.affix {
  left:15px;
  right:15px;
  width:auto;
}
}

.affix + .container {
 padding: 0px;
}

h1, h4 {
 text-shadow: 4px 5px 3px #A866B2; /*#DCD4F9, #F74554 moves to the right, moves down, thickness of text's shadow*/
}
.main-container {
 margin: 40px 0px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #4B004C ; /*#800000, #4B004C, #E6E6E6*/
}

#head_tag, #footer_tag {
 font-family: Tangerine, Monospace;
 color: white;
}
#head_tag {
 font-size: 100px;
 height: 300px;
}
#footer_tag {
 font-size: 50px;
}

.image {
 border-style: solid;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #000;
 height: 230px;
 width: 240px;
}
.img-responsive {
 margin: 20px auto;
}

.navbar {
 margin: 0px 20px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.info {
 font-family: Monospace;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: #E6E6E6; /*#4B004C, #E6E6E6*/
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 20px 20px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}
.boxSpacing {
 margin: 20px auto;
}
.pics {
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
}

#aboutMe, #portfolio, #contactMe {
 font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #6E326F;
}

.centeringIcon {
 display: block;
 text-align:center;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="10">
  <div class="container main-container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <h1 class="text-center" id="head_tag">Archita's Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <img src="images/Archi.jpg" class="img-responsive image">
    </div>
   </div>
     
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="365">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">  <!-- This navigation bar should not change it's width even after scrolling past it-->
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contactMe">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="info">
      <h3 class="text-center" id="aboutMe">About Me</h3>
      <p>I'm a new-bee in front-end technology. I used to work on ROR, R and Python but now I'm exploring HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, jQuery, JavaScript, AngularJS and ReactJS.</p>
      <p>I've also worked on several <span style="color:#960099">android projects </span>as well. I've also worked on highcharts and D3.</p>
     </div>

     <div class="info">
      <h3 class="text-center" id="portfolio">Portfolio</h3>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 boxSpacing">
        <img src="images/Project_1.png" class="img-responsive pics">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 boxSpacing">
        <img src="images/Project_1.png" class="img-responsive pics">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 boxSpacing">
        <img src="images/Project_1.png" class="img-responsive pics">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 boxSpacing">
        <img src="images/Project_1.png" class="img-responsive pics">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="info">
      <h3 class="text-center" id="contactMe">Contact</h3>
      <p><b>Here's my contact details:</b></p>
      <ul>
       <li>Name:- Archita Sundaray</li>
       <li>Phone no.:- +91 89514 88208</li>
       <li>email address:- archi.sundaray5@gmail.com</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <h4 class="text-center" id="footer_tag">~ made by Archita Sundaray</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 img-responsive">
     <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/archita-sundaray-b7240977/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin centeringIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 img-responsive">
     <a href="https://github.com/Archiie" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github centeringIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 img-responsive">
     <a href="https://twitter.com/Archi055" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter centeringIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 img-responsive">
     <a href="https://bitbucket.org/Archiie/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket centeringIcon"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This breaks the layout on changing the device's width. I want a solution that is responsive to device's screen.